# Algorithm for converting a 128-bit value to a string

Tags: programming, plc, algorithm, string

I am trying to convert 128-bit data to a string in a PLC, but the PLC has max. 32-bit data. I store 128-bit data as a byte array and bit array. Now I need to convert this value to a string, but the PLC does not have such a variable. I did some research, but I couldn't find the answers I wanted.

Basically I need to add the remaining numbers after multiplying their multiples in the binary system to convert a bit array to decimal. But since the number has grown so much, I can't do such a process on the PLC.

My thought is that basically the whole system is processed in binary, and it should split my 128-bit array and convert it to decimal numbers in chunks. Am I thinking wrong?

A 128-bit number has 39 characters. When you convert this number to a byte array, 16 bytes are obtained, so 16*8=128 bits. I need to expand this byte array or bit array to 39 characters again, and I have to do this without using 64-bit or 128-bit variables. I can use max. 32-bit variables.

Does anyone have any information or ideas on the subject?

---

I haven't had time to try the methods, but the threads may be useful for other friends.

@benmiller >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57845464/fastest-algorithm-to-convert-hexadecimal-numbers-into-decimal-form-without-using

@davetweed >> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85

@greybeard >> "chunk-wise two-step"

Thank you for your support.
special thanks:@benmiller , @davetweed , @greybeard

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142224/discussion-on-question-by-burak-t-algorithm-for-converting-128-bit-value-to-str).

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two ways to convert a natural number from base \$b\$ to base \$B\$:
(Following the diction of D.E. Knuth: TAoCP vol 2: Seminumerical Algorithms 4.4: Radix Conversion)

- Method (1a): *Division by* \$B\$ (using base \$b\$ arithmetic)
  (bin2dec: Division by 10)
- Method (1b): *Multiplication by* \$b\$ (using base \$B\$ arithmetic)
  (* powers of 2 "in base 10(ᵏ)")

I find "long division" a more intimidating prospect than long multiplication and suggest using 1b: computing with parts "a power of 10" - never mind how arithmetic is done "within parts".
Converting chunks of 10 bits to "millipeds" of 3 decimal digits is a bit more intuitive for a low number of chunks. Once it is working, little of the source code should change switching to groups of 4 digits (and 14-16 bits).
There sort of are two ways to go about this multiplication:

- by parameter part
  (including *double dabble* for a smart name for a basic (1 bit at a time) method)
  + doesn't need any precomputation/table(s)
  - (I think it's) more operations
- by result part (some like to call this *Vedic*)
  + (I think it's) less operations
  - needs precomputation/table(s)

Comment: Didn't get the hang of *structured text* / SCL (yet). Coded "Vedic" 4*32bit→39 digits in Java&Python 3 (~39 divisions&36 multiplications - all 31+1 bits, only); don't quite like either.

Comment: Got the same number of multiplications with *by parameter part*, but about 37-52 more divisions. (Following an addition, a "divmod" can be substituted by a conditional subtraction+change.) Has no use for the 46-72 16-bit coefficients the *by result part* variant uses to shift some divmods to initialisation/compile time.

Comment: For "method 1a" (the usual, improved by doing *4 digits per chunk*), I again got the same number of multiplications and 77 divmods. This may be teaching something about these radix conversion methods I don't get.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have BCD addition with carry available you could store 128 39-nibble constants (maybe packed 4 digits per word, but it doesn't matter as long as you can implement extensible BCD addition) representing the BCD value of 2^i for i = 0..127.

Then you iterate through the 128 bits of the unknown value, doing a BCD add of the constant (starting from zero, of course) for each '1' in the original value (and no addition if there is a zero). This is essentially multiplication with a BCD result. There's also the 'add 6' algorithm for BCD correction if BCD operations are not native.

so the array of constants would be {1, 2, 4, ... , 85070591730234615865843651857942052864, 170141183460469231731687303715884105728}

Perhaps a bit slow, but it's hard to go wrong.

If you didn't want to pre-compute the constants you could just add a register to itself in BCD, starting from 1 and compute the constants on the fly, which would take at least twice as long.

Comment: Or start with a "multiword BCD accumulator" initialised to zero, adding it to itself *with carry set to each bit from most to least significant in the original value* for the lowest accumulator word. Just 128 "long BCD additions" later (worst case), you're done.